# How to get ClosedList entities mapping in an Utterance from LUIS while exporting an App

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using this [LUIS Export programmatic API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c40) to export a LUIS app given a LUIS version.

When I am exporting the model which has List Entities(ClosedList), I am not getting the utterances which are mapped to list type of entities.

---

Please see the following JSON,

```
{
  "luis_schema_version": "2.1.0",
  "versionId": "0.1",
  "name": "DemoApp",
  "desc": "",
  "culture": "en-us",
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "Ask Person Information"
    },
    {
      "name": "None"
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "Age"
    },
    {
      "name": "Name"
    }
  ],
  "composites": [],
  "closedLists": [
    {
      "name": "Hobbies",
      "subLists": [
        {
          "canonicalForm": "Sports",
          "list": [
            "playing sports",
            "cricket",
            "football",
            "hockey",
            "chess",
            "table tennis"
          ]
        },
        {
          "canonicalForm": "Travelling",
          "list": [
            "roaming",
            "travelling",
            "travel"
          ]
        },
        {
          "canonicalForm": "Music",
          "list": [
            "playing music",
            "playing in a band",
            "band",
            "music",
            "singing"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "bing_entities": [],
  "model_features": [],
  "regex_features": [],
  "utterances": [
    {
      "text": "i am kunal and i like playing football and am 22 years old",
      "intent": "Ask Person Information",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 5,
          "endPos": 9
        },
        {
          "entity": "Age",
          "startPos": 46,
          "endPos": 47
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "i am kunal and i like music",
      "intent": "Ask Person Information",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 5,
          "endPos": 9
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "i am kunal and pushing 22",
      "intent": "Ask Person Information",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 5,
          "endPos": 9
        },
        {
          "entity": "Age",
          "startPos": 23,
          "endPos": 24
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "my name is kunal and i am 22 years old",
      "intent": "Ask Person Information",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 11,
          "endPos": 15
        },
        {
          "entity": "Age",
          "startPos": 26,
          "endPos": 27
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "hi i am kunal and 22 years old",
      "intent": "Ask Person Information",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 8,
          "endPos": 12
        },
        {
          "entity": "Age",
          "startPos": 18,
          "endPos": 19
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "hi my name is john doe and my hobbies are travelling and playing",
      "intent": "Ask Person Information",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 14,
          "endPos": 21
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Is there any way to get the utterances which are tagged to List type of entities from the Model which LUIS is exporting.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LUIS reapplies the list entities when the app is reimported and trained.

"List entities don't have to be labeled in utterances or trained by the system. 
A list entity is an explicitly specified list of values. Unlike other entity types, LUIS does not discover additional values for list entities during training. Therefore, each list entity forms a closed set."

Comment: What do you mean by: "Unlike other entity types, LUIS does not discover additional values for list entities during training."

Comment: It's a "closed list" so no additional possible values than those provided. So there's no interest in tagging the values in each utterance, they are automatically discovered as @DFBerry said